# How to add a tag to an AWS-CDK construct

Tags: aws-cdk

How to add a tag to an AWS-CDK specific construct or even better one tag definition to all ressources created within the stack?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to aws-cdk doc you can add a tag to all constructs/ressources. Tags will inherits to constructs within same "tree". That's pretty cool.

Example using aws-cdk based on java:

```
MyStack stack = new MyStack(app, "nameOfStack");
Tag.add(stack, "tag_foo", "tag_foo");
```

[AWS-Doc CDK Tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tagging.html)

[AWS CDK Reference: Tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Tag.html#static-addscope-key-value-props)

> Tags can be applied to any construct. Tags are inherited, based on the
>   scope. If you tag construct A, and A contains construct B, construct B
>   inherits the tag.

Example from aws-cdk doc:

```
import { App, Stack, Tag } from require('@aws-cdk/core');

const app = new App();
const theBestStack = new Stack(app, 'MarketingSystem');

// Add a tag to all constructs in the stack
Tag.add(theBestStack, 'StackType', 'TheBest');
```

Answer (score 53):

The accepted answer uses the deprecated syntax.

Newer version of tagging the whole App:

```js
const app = new cdk.App();
new SomeStack(app, 'SomeStack');
Tags.of(app).add("app", "my-app-name-here");
```

You could also tag individual stacks only:

```js
const app = new cdk.App();
const stack = new SomeStack(app, 'SomeStack');
Tags.of(stack).add("stack-name", "SomeStack");
```

Or individual Constructs:

```js
const usersTable = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'Users');
Tags.of(usersTable).add("owner", "team-andromeda");
```

Tags will apply to sub-Constructs hierarchically.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! This works.

Comment: How does the construct know what it's children are? Or rather -- why can the tags NOT be propagated to SOME resources in the stack?

Comment: @TomaszGandor the whole CDK app is a huge construct tree - like a pyramid, with the "CDK App" at the top, followed by Stacks as direct descendants, and then there are Constructs, with some more Constructs inside, infinite levels deep. As to how the code knows what are the children, every construct has methods that allow you to query for its list of children. I forgot what the method name was but imaging it being like `constructA.getChildren()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add tags to your CDK v2 app in `Python`, like so:

```
import aws_cdk as cdk

app = cdk.App()
cdk.Tags.of(app).add("TEAM", "TeamA") # add tags to the entire app (all resources created by this app)

lambda_stack = LambdaStack(app, 'lambda-stack')

cdk.Tags.of(lambda_stack).add("TEAM", "TeamA") # add tags to the entire stack (all resources of this stack)
```

...or to a construct:

```
lambda_role = iam.Role(self,
    assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal(service='lambda.amazonaws.com'),
    role_name='lambda-role'
)
cdk.Tags.of(lambda_role).add("TEAM", "TeamA") # add tags to this construct (add tags to just this role)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is now quite old and not valid anymore with the current CDK.
Import packages changed and I would suggest to rewrite the example like:
``` 
from aws_cdk import App, Tags
app = App()
Tags.of(app).add("TEAM", "TeamA")
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer to CDK v2.

Answer (score 1):

Because you'll likely want to add more than one Tag to a construct,
its handy to pass an object of tags.  You can use aspects in cdk to descend nodes looking for node of your type and applying whatever you want to apply to said node.
 The following example adds tags.

```
export class TagAspect implements cdk.IAspect {
 private readonly tags: Object;

 constructor(tags: Object) {
   this.tags = tags;
 }

public visit(node: cdk.IConstruct): void {
  if (node instanceof cdk.Stack) {
      Object.entries(this.tags).forEach( ([key, value]) => {
      cdk.Tag.add(node,key,value); 
  });
 }}}
```

Then in the Stack you want to apply an aspect to run 
`this.node.applyAspect(new TagAspect({"tag1":"mytag1","tag2":"another tag","tag3":"andanother"}));`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Java` SDK:

```java
public class CdkInitClusterApp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final App app = new App();
        final CdkInitClusterStack cdkInitClusterStack = new CdkInitClusterStack(app, "CdkInitClusterStack");
        Tag.add(cdkInitClusterStack, "Project", "Value");
        app.synth();
    }
}
```

Then recreate the jar

```sh
mvn clean compile package
```

And run the `cdk diff` for verify the changes, the output will be similar to the following one:

```
(base) [alessiosavi@localhost cdk-init-cluster]$ cdk diff
                   CdkInitClusterStack
Resources
[~] AWS::DynamoDB::Table cdk-test-table cdktesttableB0274F47 
 └─ [+] Tags
     └─ [{"Key":"Project","Value":"Value"}]
```