# AWS cdk how to tag resources in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, aws-cdk

I am trying to get Tags to work in a C# AWS CDK project but I can't seem to get anything to work except for the Depreciated syntax.  For example in the following code:

```
using Amazon.CDK;
using Amazon.CDK.AWS.S3;

namespace HelloCdk
{
    public class HelloCdkStack : Stack
    {
        internal HelloCdkStack(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)  
        {
            // The code that defines your stack goes here
            var g_bucket = new Bucket(this, "GameContent", new BucketProps
            {
                Versioned = false, 
                PublicReadAccess = true,
                AutoDeleteObjects = true,              //delete and 
                RemovalPolicy = RemovalPolicy.DESTROY, //destroy bucket when CF Stack deleted.
                WebsiteIndexDocument = "index.html",
                WebsiteErrorDocument = "index.html"
            });

            Tag.Add(g_bucket, "key", "value");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will succeed when I issue the `cdk synth` command.  However, I get a warning message that says:

> warning CS0618: 'Tag.Add(Construct, string, string, ITagProps?)' is obsolete: 'use "Tags.of(scope).add()"'

But, when I try to use "Tags.of...", the `cdk synth` command throws the following error:

> error CS1061: 'TagManager' does not contain a definition for 'of' and no accessible extension method 'of'...

What do I need to change to get the recommended tagging approach to work?

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64587781/14072498

Comment: Thanks Roar, but the code in the question that you linked to is not structured the same as that which is created when you use the `cdk init app --language csharp` command. 
 That command creates a structure like that posted in my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source code with `Tags.of` should not compile as there is no such a method for .NET defined.

Documentation specifies `Tags.Of` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tagging.html

> Tags.Of(myConstruct).Add("key", "value");

(!) Notice that the stack object has the Tags property, so make sure you do not access the Tags property of the stack, but Tags class.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work either.  Still get the following error:   `error CS1061: 'TagManager' does not contain a definition for 'Of' and no accessible extension method 'of'...`

Comment: Okay, I tried to replicate your issue and probably see the root cause. As the Stack has the Tags property, you might unintentionally access the property instead of the Tags class. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to replicate the issue and for the updated response. Makes sense now - things are working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the correct Tags class in `Amazon.CDK` namespace, and not the `Stack.Tags` property. Here's how you can get to it directly:

```
Amazon.CDK.Tags.Of(CONSTRUCT).Add(KEY, VALUE);
```